# Out of memory Application crash React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Using React Native 0.33
After some seconds, the application stops (only tested on Android)

Looking at the android logs I get :

[image]

I have no idea how to examine the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this fixes my issue:

Add this to your "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<application android:largeHeap="true"
```

ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6799

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" doing this without inspecting whats using more memory is never a good idea, it basically just delays and hides potential memory issues like memory leaks.

Comment: @AmeyaB What is a better way to fix this?

Comment: is there a largeHeap option for iOS on react native?

Comment: add leakCanary to detect memory leaks and try to fix it. enabling largeHeap should be the solution only if you genuinely need more memory.(example games)

Answer (score 6):

Using the below might help you

```
    <application android:largeHeap="true">
```

But you might need to check your application for possible memory leaks. for eg:

1. Unreleased timers/listeners added in componentDidMount
2. Closure scope leaks.
3. Large image sizes.
4. Use of global variables.

We were facing the same issues with our react native app. It took us a lot of time and effort in making our apps somewhat stable. You can check out this blog which helped us a lot https://blog.swmansion.com/hunting-js-memory-leaks-in-react-native-apps-bd73807d0fde

Update:
Loading large amount of data in API continuously was putting load on the RAM at least on low end devices causing Out of Memory issues. You will need to clean this up as well and find a better and optimised way to load data.

Answer (score 0):

For Android: in manifest file Android tag

```
application android:largeHeap="true" 
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

[For iOS](https://sandny.com/2019/12/30/react-native-heap-limit-allocation-failed/) :Bundle React Native code and imagessection under the Build Phases

```
export NODE_BINARY=node 
export NODE_ARGS=--max-old-space-size=8192
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

Also if your app loading image from web then use below lib

```
https://github.com/fungilation/react-native-cached-image
```