# Flatlist with video streaming, React Native, Expo, runs into memory problems on Android

Tags: react-native, expo, video-streaming, flatlist, expo-av

Expo app with flatlist and one video per line. (cf. TikTok)

- Expo SDK 40.0.0
- Flatlist - optimised (shouldComponentUpdate) + see props, max 2 lines are rendered at the same time. There is a clean unmount of the lines not in the field of view. Only the video in the field of view runs, the 2nd one pauses.
- Expo-AV
- Google-Firebase Cloudstorage: the videos are also generated and uploaded by the app.

**Problem**:
At the latest after the 4th video is rendered the app runs into a memory problem on Android. From the beginning NO problems on IOS devices.
Error message/warning: VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update .... After that, the videos do not load at all for a long time, only after a few minutes do the two videos to be rendered appear again.

**Component structure:**

- VideoStream - React.Component => all data available and stored in
  the Redux store.
- Flatlist => only 7 records are passed, see flatlist props
- Item => via renderItem
- VideoItem - React.Component> => incl. GestureHandle, Background
- TouchableOpacity>
- Video => Expo-AV

  ```
   <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
         snapToAlignment={'start'}
         snapToInterval={screenHeight}
         decelerationRate={'fast'}
         scrollEventThrottle={250}
         pagingEnabled
         showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
         vertical={true}
         scrollEnabled={true}
         style={{flex: 1}}
         data={videos}
         renderItem={this.renderItem}
         keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
         onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
         initialNumToRender={0}
         maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
         windowSize={2}
         getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
         onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
         onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
         viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
         removeClippedSubviews={true}
       />
   </View>
    viewabilityConfig = {
       itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 75,
    };
  ```

**Tested:**

- both Stream and loadAsync => same behaviour.
- alternative public data sources => same behaviour
- no videos to load => no problem

**Hypotheses:**

- Android - and Expo-AV: on IOS without problems stacks have been
  regularly found since about 2018, unfortunately so far without
  solutions, based on a connection between Expo player and Android
- Upload - which errors/optimisations are possible
- Download - which errors/optimisations are possible?

After 10 days of optimisation & search for causes, now my call for help .... Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a react native question ? if so, please tag it accordingly

Comment: we are running into similar issues. Something my logcat notices is that expo-av will cause ExoPlayer to throw this error: 2021-04-19 08:36:06.565 10559-10559/? W/SimpleExoPlayer: Player is accessed on the wrong thread. See https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/faqs.html#what-do-player-is-accessed-on-the-wrong-thread-warnings-mean
Check your logcat as well. There likely is some low level issue with expo, or unimodules where its not properly releasing memory for cleanup by the VM

Comment: UPDATE:
I switched to RecyclerListView (https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) - highly recommended.
Ok, much more effort in the details, but at the end of the day it was more than worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with expo-av and react native.
I used the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655791/out-of-memory-application-crash-react-native)
I am sure is not the best one but at least is working.