# How to increase React Native Application memory ? Getting Out of memory during Get Api call

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting out of memory error when I'm trying to request Get API whose response is like 60-80mb size. It responses work properly on Postman and on Web application but crashes my react-native mobile application and pop's "Out of Memory" error. Are there any ways to increase my react-native application memory.
This Get Api response base64 which can be pdf or image

```
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.9",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.13.18",
```

app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
   

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.enterprisesales.uat"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            zipAlignEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            useProguard enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
     

    // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
         
 

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    compile project(':react-native-exit-app')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

AndroidManifest.xml File

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.uat">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

API Call Function Get Request

```
const url = `${Config.ApiEndPoints.API_GET_DOCUMENT}
const header = { "Authorization": `Bearer ${Config.UserSession.USER_DATA.token}` }
const apiResponse = await Module.ApiModule.GetRequest(url, header)
const baseResponse = await fetch(url, {
        method: TYPE === undefined ? "GET" : TYPE,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            ...header
        },
    }).then(r => r.json()).catch(error => {
        Module.DropDownAlert.showAlert("error", Config.String.SOME_ERROR_OCCURS, Config.String.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG)
        return null
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the memory [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655791/out-of-memory-application-crash-react-native). You should look at the 60-80MB API response though. I don't know what kind of data you're fetching, but it's not gonna be a nice UX when there's an API call with that size being made.

Comment: the link which you have provide i'm already using that solution but its not use. I'm fetching base64 of pdf file from that Get api.