# App crash on some devices after taking image in React Native

Tags: react-native, crash, android-camera, react-native-image-crop-picker

The issue is that the app crashes and restarts from the splash screen when taking an image. This problem doesn't occur on all phones; it's specific to some models like the SM-A105F with API level 30, CPH2477, and a few others. Most phones don't experience this issue.

I run adb logcat | grep com.example.myapp command in debug mode and I found this problem. I'm sharing it on Codeshare: https://codeshare.io/EBmO4v.

When taking one picture from 4 to 12, no line occurred, and the app worked fine during this time. However, taking another picture, the problem emerged between lines 27 to 62, causing the app to crash and then automatically restart.

Comment: I leave the link here. You examine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655791/out-of-memory-application-crash-react-native

Comment: Saw the link and applied, But still have the same issue on some particular devices. I am literally surfing around on the internet. But didn't get any answer.